# how to filter data by the number of unique values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data that I would like to investigate and would like to pull out
all features which have a certain number of unique values, whether that's 2,
5, 10, etc.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this though.

For example :

```
tst = data.frame(
  a = c(1,1,1,0,0),
  b = c(1,2,3,3,3),
  c = c(1,2,3,4,4),
  d = c(1,2,3,4,5)
)
tst

tst %>% 
  filter(<variables with x unique values>)
```

Where `x=2`  would just filter to `a`, `x=3` filter to `b`, etc

Comment: Unclear to me what do you want to do. Are you counting the unique number of each column?

Comment: Do you mean you want to `select` the columns with a specific number of unique values? `filter` is for keeping rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `select_if` with the `n_distinct` function.

```
tst %>% 
  select_if(~n_distinct(.) == 2)
#   a
# 1 1
# 2 1
# 3 1
# 4 0
# 5 0
```

Comment: thanks, I'm not too sure what the tilde is for here, I'm familiar with it in terms of `plot(y ~ x)`, but I'm not sure if that transfers to this.

Comment: `select_if` passes its first argument to `as_function`. The output of `as_function` is the function used to decide which columns to return (those for which the function returns `TRUE`). The input of `as_function` needs to be either "a function ... used as is" or "A formula, e.g. `~ .x + 2`" in which case "it is converted to a function ... The `.` placeholder can be used instead of `.x`.". So the tilde is used to create a formula, which `as_function` converts to a function, which `select_if` applies to all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way in base R:

```
x <- 2
tst[, apply(tst, 2, function(row) length(unique(row))) == x, drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 0):

This example code will create a variable combination of abcd. Then will identify which are duplicate combinations, then will return only those combinations that are not duplicates. I hope this is what you were asking for...

```
tst = data.frame(
   a = c(1,1,1,0,0),
   b = c(1,2,3,3,3),
   c = c(1,2,3,4,4),
   d = c(1,2,3,4,5)
  )
tst %>%
  unite(new,a,b,c,d,sep="") %>%
  mutate(duplicate=duplicated(new)) %>%
  filter(duplicate !="TRUE")
```