# Filter dataframe by how many times they occur et al

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataframe called `Revenue` where some dates, cities and revenues are illustrated.

```
Date                      City               Revenue
1989-02-25                LA                 50
1989-02-25                NY                 72
1989-02-25                PAR                65
1989-02-25                ROM                71
1989-02-26                NY                 82
1989-02-26                BAC                73
1989-02-27                TOK                55
1989-02-27                BTH                83
1989-02-27                PAR                69
1989-02-27                NY                 70
1989-02-28                NY                 45
1989-03-01                HEL                95
#With 7000 more rows
```

**What I'm trying to do is to select dates which occurs four times, in this example above 1989-02-25 and 1989-02-27 and so forth.** The tibble should look something like this:

```
Date                      City               Revenue
1989-02-25                LA                 50
1989-02-25                NY                 72
1989-02-25                PAR                65
1989-02-25                ROM                71
1989-02-27                TOK                55
1989-02-27                BTH                83
1989-02-27                PAR                69
1989-02-27                NY                 70
#With 1251 more rows
```

**Next step is to filter dates so only dates that has a revenue at or above 45 is included my tibble.** The first rows will look like above but there should be a reduced amount of rows.

**After that the tibble should be constrained by showing the lowest amount of a revenue per a date.** So it looks like this (city is removed here) `Revenue$city <- NULL`:

```
Date                        Revenue
1989-02-25                  50
1989-02-27                  55
#With 57 more rows
```

Anyone has any ideas? Quite challenging with so many steps.

Comment: One question per question please! If you look up each of these steps separately, you'll be able to find answers.

Comment: Do you mean average or lowest values above 40?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the number of elements with the values of x in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923273/counting-the-number-of-elements-with-the-values-of-x-in-a-vector)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to filter data by the number of unique values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269779/how-to-filter-data-by-the-number-of-unique-values-in-r)

Comment: @socialscientist . Absolutely. I understand.

Comment: @dcsuka I'm looking for lowest value above 45. Will take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that involves some grouped filtering.

```r
df <- read.table(text = "Date                      City               Revenue
1989-02-25                LA                 50
1989-02-25                NY                 72
1989-02-25                PAR                65
1989-02-25                ROM                71
1989-02-26                NY                 82
1989-02-26                BAC                73
1989-02-27                TOK                55
1989-02-27                BTH                83
1989-02-27                PAR                69
1989-02-27                NY                 70
1989-02-28                NY                 45
1989-03-01                HEL                95") %>%
  janitor::row_to_names(1) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::ymd(Date),
         Revenue = as.integer(Revenue)) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  filter(n() == 4,
         Revenue > 45) %>%
  summarise(Revenue = min(Revenue))

# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   Date       Revenue
#   <date>       <int>
# 1 1989-02-25      50
# 2 1989-02-27      55
```